# 'and' in bibtex with multiple authors does not supported in context?

Tags: bibtex, context

I have a simple database:

```
@misc{curs-adults-1,
 author= "Alzina Seguí, Pere and Rosselló, Ramon",
 title = "Estratègies metodològiques per a l'ensenyament d'adults",
 year = "2016"
}
```

Which I cited in ConTeXt file:

```
\cite[curs-adults-1]. Alguns dels...
```

I get **and** in the bibliography instead of comma (as usual with several authors)
[image]

I use MKIV 0.63 (2016.05.17 19:20)

Comment: How did you set your bibliography up? A minimal working example (MWE) would be helpful.

Comment: Aerhm, isn't it traditional that there is an **and** and not a comma when it is jut two authors? As DG' says, please provide a full minimal example and an entry with more than two authors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to redefine the names separator for authors in the list.

```
\startbuffer[references]
@misc{curs-adults-1,
 author= "Alzina Seguí, Pere and Rosselló, Ramon",
 title = "Estratègies metodològiques per a l'ensenyament d'adults",
 year = "2016"
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[references.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]

\setupbtx
  [aps:list:author]
  [separator:names:3={\btxcomma},
   separator:names:4={\btxcomma}]

\starttext

\cite[curs-adults-1]

\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share some document for reference? I just found [this](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf) but almost nothing in [wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/)

Comment: What do you mean by "share"?  Technically I'm already this document right here.  The MKIV bibliographies are not documented on the Wiki because there exists the fantastic and extensive PDF documentation you linked.  There are other things that are not properly documented in the Wiki because there exist actual books about them like fonts in MKIV or Metafun.  You can find a collection of all the additional sources on the [Manuals page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Manuals) in the Garden.