# Possible bug: references appear in blue

Tags: context

I have this context file:

```
\enableregime[utf]
\mainlanguage[ca]

\setupbodyfont [cmr,12pt] % cmr, 11pt
\setuphead[chapter,section][page=yes]
\setupinteraction[state=start, color=blue, style=\tf]
\setupurl[color=blue, style=\tf]

% De https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367929/and-in-bibtex-with-multiple-authors-does-not-supported-in-context/367938#367938
\usebtxdataset[bibliografia]
\usebtxdefinitions[aps] % aps, apa

\setupbtx
  [aps:list:author]
  [separator:names:3={\btxcomma},
   separator:names:4={\btxcomma}]


\starttext

\section{Motivació i objectius}

\subsection{Motivació}


\input ward


\subsection{Objectius}

\input ward \cite[building-thinking-classrooms]

\section{Referències}

\startcolor[black]
\placelistofpublications
\stopcolor

\stoptext
```

and I get `\placelistofpublications` in blue, instead of black, even when I impose black color. Why?

[image]

Comment: It uses the color from `\setupinteraction`.

Comment: 1.) This is not the place to report bugs.  2.) This has already been reported [on the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086227.html) some time ago.  Try with latest beta and see if it still turns up.  3.) Your example is incomplete and does not match the output (bibliography missing).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report rather than a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary workaround:  Remove the colour from the list rendering.  This will also remove the colour from the link but that's better than having the whole line coloured.

```
\startbuffer[references]
@article{curs-adults-1,
  author= "Alzina Seguí, Pere and Rosselló, Ramon",
  title = "Estratègies metodològiques per a l'ensenyament d'adults",
  year = "2016",
  journal = "TeX.SX",
  url = "https://tex.stackexchange.com/"
}
\stopbuffer

\setupinteraction[state=start]

\usebtxdataset[references.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]

\appendtoks
  \iflocation
    \letinteractionparameter{color}\empty
  \fi
\to \everybtxlistrendering

\starttext

\cite[curs-adults-1]

\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

[image]